# Importing Spears SDIF Files Into Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have Mex files for SDIF format that imports these files into matlab for further processing, my question is how to use these mex files and which matlab directory to put them, as running the default function gives me errors, could matlab versions be conflicting.

Here is more info on the SDIF format;
SDIF file is an audio file that carries phase, frequency and amplitude values of an audio signal, I need to take these values of phase frequency and amplitude into matlab so I can use them for generating new signals that carry these aspects that we can acquire from the SDIF files...

I have the mex files and some matlab code to import Spears SDIF files "Sound Description Interchange Format 
extensions for Matlab" into matlab, but I am having a difficulty importing my sdif files into matlab... 
[link to mex files and matlab code](http://recherche.ircam.fr/equipes/analyse-synthese/sdif//download/sdif-matlab)

Comment: Please use "enter" to make new lines, this is unreadable.

Comment: Please tell us what your problems are. We cannot help you otherwise. Check out [ask], and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the "sdif-matlab-0.3.0-winxp.zip" that one has working mex files.

Comment: OP did not even mention their OS ...